# Why is answering my own question considered as blocking others from answering it?

Tags: discussion

Why is answering my own question considered as blocking others from answering it? After all, an option to "Answer your question" is offered.

> Quote
>
> Your question is not clear, but becomes clearer with your own answer
>   which coincided, more or less, with your own question. You seem to be
>   excluding other users from your own process. – Nigel J Nov 12 at 9:25

[What did Paul believe about 1 Corinthians 10:4 with regards to the teaching about bread from heaven, spiritual food?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/74142/what-did-paul-believe-about-1-corinthians-104-with-regards-to-the-teaching-abou)

Answer (score 6):

The question should be self-contained, so that anyone can answer it. If your question is unclear in itself, and is clarified only by your accompanying answer, then it's a poor question, and should be edited to improve.

Answering your own question is perfectly acceptable, but you need to be careful not to [skimp on question quality](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/307/581). The question will be judged as a question in itself, independent of your accompanying answer.

Comment: What is unclear about it?

Comment: I think the problem is not that the question is unclear, but that it is off-topic.  Asking what Paul believed about something, especially if he didn't explicitly state so, is a "truth question".  "Truth questions" are off-topic on this site.  See https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/we-cant-handle-the-truth